# How to convert a list/ array to midi?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, signal-processing, midi

I am doing some research about audio signals, and new to this section. I'm wondering if there are some tools for giving a list of values, then it could convert into a midi. For example, if I have a list like

```py
length = [0.93,0.12,0.84,0.98,1.23,1.04]
```

It means the time of each note. Thus, the first note and the section has 0.93 duration, and the second and third third has 0.12 duration.

Hope someone could give me some resources or codes, I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 2):

Apart from duration notes need to have also their pitch (frequency) and loudness.

Take a look at this package (DISCLAIMER: I never used it, just documentation looks good):
https://mido.readthedocs.io/en/latest/midi_files.html#creating-a-new-file